# Django-rest-framework: return Response from .dispatch

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am doing a (more-or-less) custom authentication in a `django-rest-framework`-based application, where I just need to call another microservice to ask it if a token is valid and what username/userid are associated with it. (I don't have a local table for users).

Having found no out-of-the-box solution, I am overriding the `dispatch` method (I am using a `APIView`-based view), where I make the request to the remote service and, if the response is not 200, I want to return a 403 error.

Here's my code:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user_info = user_from_token_in_request(request)
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        return Response(
            "No Auth Token provided or bad Auth Token"
            status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
        )
```

However, when I pass an invalid token, I get this error: `AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response`, because the response context is not initialised when the `dispatch` method is processed.

Is there a, sort of, more proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning the `Response` try raising one of the exceptions provided by `DRF`, and its exception handler would automatically handle the rest.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # ...
    except:
        raise PermissionDenied("NO Auth Token provided")
```

With that said, it is not recommended to write your authentication code in your view itself. You should have done this in a custom authentication/permission class.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication

class MyAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        try:
            user_info = user_from_token_in_request(request)
        except:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('No auth token provided')

class MyApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [MyAuthentication]
```

Also make sure, you have defined `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` in your rest framework settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: In that case, the response that the client gets is 500

Comment: @Ibolit Have you defined Rest framework exception handler in settings.

Comment: I also tried implementing the .handle_exception, but it doesn't get called for an exception in dispatch.

Comment: @hspandler No, I will look into it.

Comment: Yep, writing a proper authentication class worked a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

To answer the original question, `handle_exception` is called inside `dispatch`, so if you are overriding `dispatch`, it will not be called automatically for you. BUT you can call it directly:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class SometimesErrorMixin:
    should_error = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.should_error:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Lifted from DRF
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

        response = self.handle_exception(PermissionDenied())
        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
```

Put this Mixin left most on a ViewSet to use the behavior. Obviously you can replace `should_error` with the appropriate logic.